# check if a child is present ? if present only then execute a particular method

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

i have a user logged in and i want to check if that user has a child node "following" . . how do i check it.. ?

this is how i created user

```
                        var userId = authData.uid

                        let newUser = [
                            "Provider" : authData.provider,
                            "email"    : authData.providerData["email"] as? NSString as? String,
                            "name"     : self.Name.text,
                            "location" : "",
                            "about"    : "",
                            "age"      : "",
                        ]



self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(authData.uid).setValue(newUser)
```

the child node "following" will be created when a logged in user searches a friend and clicks on the follow button, it will have the following structure after creation.it will have the UID(of the searched user)as KEY 
and email (of the searched user) as value.

USERS

simplelogin3

- age : 24
- Name: mike
- email : mike@gmail.com
- following

  - simplelogin6 : "abc@hotmail.com"

but my question is only this, that what should i code just to check if there is a child node "following" in the logged in user or not? ,,  please help i am new to firebase and swift

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line of code using `if let`:

```
if let childNode = newUser["following"] {
    println(childNode)
}
```

If your user hasn't a following key it won't execute the code between closures.

Comment: instead of newUser i wrote ref.authData.uid bcoz i m not performing this on the same view controller where i created ref ! 

but it is giving me an error! ..  this is not the way to do it i guess ,, there must be some another way!

Comment: can anybody please help i m really confused :(

Comment: what exactly do u want?

Comment: The code where you tried to do something and it gives you an error.

Comment: ref.childByAppendingPath("users").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
        
            if let childNode = self.ref.authData.uid["following"] {
            
            
            }
        })




"error" :

type "String Index" does not conform to protocol "string literal convertible"

Comment: try `if let childNode = snapshot.value {}` and print what it will show you

Answer (score 0):

Using the Null checking method i solved this problem,

```
  ref.observeSingleEventOfType(>value, withBlock:{snapshot in
 if snapshot.value is NSNull {
// do this }  'else {
```

// do this

}

})'